# Set a default location for the map to start at - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary

How do you set a default location for the map to start at? If I want to set it in Ireland for example, how would I do that? It currently defaults to around North America but I want it to default to a certain coordinates.

Comment: Refer setRegion:animated: method of MKMapView class at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/setRegion:animated:.

Answer (score 3):

The below code sets location to SFO. Change coordinates to your needs to set desired locations.

```
MKCoordinateRegion region = [mapView regionThatFits:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.78275123, -122.40345442), 200, 200)];
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

If you are looking for user's current location, use below code.

```
MKCoordinateRegion region = [mapView regionThatFits:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(mapView.userLocation.coordinate, 200, 200)];
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

Comment: The first code example isn't right.  MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance takes a CLLocationCoordinate2D as the first parameter (not an MKMapPoint).  In addition, `mapView.userCenterCoordinate.coordinate` is invalid (mapView has no such property and userCenterCoordinate which is declared as MKMapPoint has no coordinate property).  Finally, calling regionThatFits is unnecessary here since setRegion itself will do it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setRegion:animated` to set the initial region of the `MKMapView`:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

self.mapView.delegate = self;

double delayInSeconds = 0.5;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
    region.center.latitude = 45.442424;
    region.center.longitude = -122.78;
    region.span.latitudeDelta =  0.60;
    region.span.longitudeDelta =  0.60;
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
});
}
```