# How to set custom location in iOS programmatically?

Tags: objective-c

How to set custom location in iOS programmatically?

I am trying to customize user's current location in iOS programmatically.

Comment: Use CLLocationmanager to get the users current location

Answer (score 0):

```
MKCoordinateRegion region = [mapView regionThatFits:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(mapView.userLocation.coordinate, 200, 200)];
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

[Set a default location for the map to start at - iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913889/set-a-default-location-for-the-map-to-start-at-ios)